Isometry on product Riemannian manifold acts on each component separately
I am reading On loops representing elements of the fundamental group of a complete manifold with nonnegative Ricci curvature by Sormani. I'm confused when reading the following statement:

Assume that $M$ is a manifold with nonnegative Ricci curvature which contains a line. So by the Splitting Theorem of Cheeger and Gromoll, $M$ splits isometrically into $N^{n-k}\times \mathbb R^k$ where $N^{n-k}$ has no lines and $k \geq 1$.
If $F:M\to M$ is an isometry, then it acts on each component seperately. That is $F|_N:N\to N$ and $F|_{\mathbb R^k}:\mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R^k$ are both isometries.

I'm confused about "then it acts on each component seperately. That is $F=F|_N:N\to N$ and $F=F|_{\mathbb R^k}:\mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R^k$ are both isometries."
My understanding is $F|_N=\pi_N\circ F\circ\pi_N^{-1}$ and $F|_{\mathbb R^k}=\pi_{\mathbb R^k}\circ F\circ\pi_{\mathbb R^k}^{-1}$.
\begin{matrix}
N\times\mathbb R^k & \overset F\longrightarrow & N\times\mathbb R^k \\
\pi_N\downarrow\quad~ &  & \pi_N\downarrow\quad~ \\
N & \color{red}{\underset{F~|_N}\longrightarrow} & N
\end{matrix}
Hence to ensure $F|_N$ and $F|_{\mathbb R^k}$ are both well-defined, we must prove the following claim:
Claim. For any $p\in N$ and $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb R^k$, $\pi_N(F(p,x_1))=\pi_N(F(p,x_2))$. And for any $p_1,p_2\in N$ and $x\in\mathbb R^k$, $\pi_{\mathbb R^k}(F(p_1,x))=\pi_{\mathbb R^k}(F(p_2,x))$.
If the claim is true, then let $V=(V_N,V_{\mathbb R^k})$, $W=(W_N,W_{\mathbb R^k})$ be vector fields on $M$, so we have
\begin{align*}
 &\quad g_N(V_N,W_N)+g_{\mathbb R^k}(V_{\mathbb R^k},W_{\mathbb R^k})\\
 &=g_M(V,W)\\
 &=(F^*g_M)(V,W)\\
 &=g_M(F_*(V_N,0)+F_*(0,V_{\mathbb R^k}),F_*(W_N,0)+F_*(0,W_{\mathbb R^k}))\\
 &\color{red}=g_N((F|_N)_*V_N,(F|_N)_*W_N)+g_{\mathbb R^k}((F|_{\mathbb R^k})_*V_{\mathbb R^k},(F|_{\mathbb R^k})_*W_{\mathbb R^k})\\
 &=((F|_N)^*g_N)(V_N,W_N)+((F|_{\mathbb R^k})^*g_{\mathbb R^k})(V_{\mathbb R^k},W_{\mathbb R^k}),
\end{align*}
where we used the claim in the red equality. In particular, take $V_{\mathbb R^k}=W_{\mathbb R^k}=0$, then we get $g_N=(F|_N)^*g_N$, and take $V_N=W_N=0$, then we get $g_{\mathbb R^k}=(F|_{\mathbb R^k})^*g_{\mathbb R^k}$.
Now it suffices to prove the claim, but I'm stuck here. Any help would be appreciated!

The point is that since the decomposition $N\times \mathbb R^k$ is unique, it is necessarily preserved under an isometry.

@MikhailKatz Could you further explain the details? I think I may have missed something very trivial.

Given that $F: M \to M$ is an isometry, let $N_s = N \times \{s\}$ for $s\in \mathbb R^k$. For each $(p, s)\in M$, we have the splitting
$$\tag{1} T_{(p,s)} M \cong T_p N_s \oplus \mathbb R^k$$
and we identity both $T_pN_s$, $\mathbb R^k$ as subspaces of $T_{(p, s)}M$.
Let $p\in N_s$ and let $F(p,s) = (\bar p, \bar s)$.
Claim: $F_* T_p N_s = T_{\bar p} N_{\bar s}$.
Proof of claim: Let $v\in T_p N_s$ and let $\gamma$ be a geodesic in $M$ with $$\gamma (0) = (p, s), \ \ \gamma'(0) = (v,0).$$
Since $N$ is totally geodesic, $\gamma$ lies completely in $N_s$.
Write $F_* (v,0)= (v_1, v_2)$, where $v_1 \in T_{\bar p} N_{\bar s}$ and $v_2\in \mathbb R^k$. Let $\gamma_1(t)$ be a geodesic in $N$ with $\gamma_1(0) = \bar p$ and $\gamma_1'(0) = v_1$. Let $\gamma_2 (t) = \bar s + tv_2$. Then
$$ \bar \gamma (t) := (\gamma_1(t), \gamma_2(t))$$
is a geodesic in $M$ with
$$\bar \gamma(0) = (\bar p, \bar s)= F(p, s)=F(\gamma(0))$$
and
$$\bar\gamma'(0) =(v_1,v_2)= F_* (v, 0)=F_*\gamma'(0).$$
Since $F$ is an isometry, we must have $\bar \gamma(t) = F(\gamma(t))$ for all $t$. Since $\gamma$ lies in $N_s$ which contains no line and $\gamma_2(t) = \bar s + tv_2$, we conclude that $v_2 = 0$. Hence $F_* T_p N_s \subset T_{\bar p} N_{\bar s}$.
By the claim we conclude that $F(N_s) = N_{\bar s}$. Also, using the isometric splitting (1), we also conclude that $F_*$ preserves $\mathbb R^k_p = \{p \} \times \mathbb R^k$. Let $(p, s)$ be fixed and
$$G : N \to N, G(q) = \pi_1 \circ F(q, s),\ \ \ H : \mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R^k, H(u) = \pi_2 \circ F(p, u).$$
and let $\tilde F : M\to M$ be the isometry of $M$ given by
$$\tilde F(q, u) = (G(q), H(u)).$$
A priori, $\tilde F$ depends on the choice $(p, s)$. However since $F(p, s) = \tilde F(p, s)$, $F_* = \tilde F_*$ at $(p, s)$ and both $F,\tilde F$ are isometies, we conclude that $F = \tilde F$. Hence $F$ splits into a product.
